# Set visible property of fields in a PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext, acrobat

I have a PDF template file with a button field on it. Let's say, the name of the button field in "Button1". Is it possible to hide this button from my java application using iText (v5.5)?

Comment: Which version are you using? The answer provided assumes you're using iText 7. Please fix your first sentence. Saying you have a *static PDF* with a *button field* is a contradiction. A *static PDF* is a PDF without a form. A *button field* implies that the PDF contains a form (and therefore isn't static). You also don't mention if you're creating the from scratch (`PdfWriter`) or if you're talking about an existing PDF (`PdfReader`). As long as you don't show any code, we can't even guess.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. I've updated the question. Any idea how we can do this in v 5.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the [HideButton](http://developers.itextpdf.com/node/2196#2563-hidebutton.java) example. In this example, we take a PDF named [hello_button.java](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/resources/pdfs/hello_button.pdf) that has a button named `"Test"` (the gray area in the screen shot):

[image]

The field with name `"Text"` corresponds with one widget annotation. We can change the flags of this annotation like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
form.setFieldProperty("Test", "setflags", PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_HIDDEN, null);
stamper.close();
```

The result of this operation is a file named [hello_button_hidden.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/acroforms/cmp_hello_button_hidden.pdf):

[image]

This is the iText 5 answer; the other answer was an iText 7 answer.

Answer (score 1):

See [PDFFormField.setVisibility(int visibility)](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/7.0.0/com/itextpdf/forms/fields/PdfFormField.html#setVisibility-int-) and [PDFAcroForm.getField(String fieldName)](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/7.0.0/com/itextpdf/forms/PdfAcroForm.html#getField-java.lang.String-)

Your code will look something like this:

```
pdfAcroform.getField("Button1").setVisibility(PDFFormField.HIDDEN);
```

Comment: That's an iText 7 answer. The OP doesn't mention if he's using iText 7 (in which case your answer will help him) or iText 5 (in which case a different answer is needed). It's also not clear what is meant by a *static PDF*. Usually a static PDF means that it doesn't contain any form fields. However, this is contradicted by the statement that there's a button field. You are trying to provide a good answer to a bad question ;-)

Comment: It is possible in iText 5.5, but the code is different.